# name 'classification_model' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

Im trying to model in Python 3.5 and am following an example that can be found at [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/01/complete-tutorial-learn-data-science-python-scratch-2/).

I have imported all the required libraries from sklearn.

However I'm getting the following error.

Code:

```
  from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
  from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold   #For K-fold cross validation
  from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
  from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, export_graphviz
  from sklearn import metrics

 outcome_var = 'Loan_Status'
 model = LogisticRegression()
 predictor_var = ['Credit_History']
 classification_model(model, loan,predictor_var,outcome_var)
```

When I run the above code I get the following error:
     **NameError: name 'classification_model' is not defined**

I'm not sure how to resolve this as I tried importing sklearn and all the sub libraries.

P.S. I'm new to Python, hence I'm trying to figure out basic steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the exact details this may not be what you want but I have never had a problem with

```
 import sklearn.linear_model as sk

 logreg = sk.LogisticRegressionCV()
 logreg.fit(predictor_var,outcome_var)
```

This means you have to explicitly separate your training and test set, but having fit to a training set (the process in the final line of my code), you can then use the methods detailed in the documentation [1].

For example figuring out what scores (how many did I get correct) you get on unseen data with the .score method

[1] http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV.html

Comment: Note that LogisticRegressionCV at the end does your cross validation for selecting a suitable regularisation parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It appears this code came from [this tutorial](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/01/complete-tutorial-learn-data-science-python-scratch-2/).

The issue is exactly as the error describes. `classification_model` is currently undefined. You need to create this function yourself before you can call it. Check out [this](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/01/complete-tutorial-learn-data-science-python-scratch-2/#stb-container-6376) part of that tutorial so you can see how it's defined. Good luck!

Comment: Is there any in built package, for creating the model. (Like R)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `model` is built using the `LogisticRegression()` class which is part of the sklearn package. I'm not very familiar with sklearn but following that tutorial from beginning to end seems like your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.